# pig script: join tables with null values

Tags: apache-pig

I'd like to join 2 tables, and I'm a bit lost with different kinds of joins

```
A(a_name:chararray, a_number:int)
a    1
b    2
c    
d    3
e    

B(b_id:int, b_name:chararray)
1    one
2    two
3    three
```

I know that I need to some sort of join, but with

```
AB = JOIN A by a_number, B by b_id;
FOREACH AB GENERATE
    a_name,
    b_name as a_number;
```

I get

```
a    one
b    two
d    three
```

Instead of

```
a    one
b    two
c    
d    three
e
```

which I actually want.
How should I do this?

edit:

Ok, I tried left join but it doesn't keep the row order and instead returns

```
a    one
b    two
d    three
c    
e
```

Any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a [left `JOIN`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#join-outer).
                                                             [image: A left join]
This will keep all values on the left side of the relationship even if they don't appear in the right. Pig defaults to an inner `JOIN`, so it only keeps values that are in both sides.

This will now generate what you expect.

```
AB = JOIN A by a_number LEFT, B by b_id;
C = FOREACH AB GENERATE a_name, b_name AS a_number;
```

Also, you should be able to compact those two relations into:

```
AB = FOREACH (JOIN A by a_number LEFT, B by b_id)
     GENERATE a_name, b_name AS a_number;
```

As far as I know there is no option in `JOIN` to perverse the order of the left relation.  However, you can [`RANK`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#rank) `A` beforehand then [`ORDER`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#order-by) on the number `RANK` creates after the `JOIN`.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you.
That left join illustration picture was usefull and reminded me to look the others too. If I would finally remember what join did what.

Comment: A minor correction: syntax is actually 'AB = JOIN A by a_number LEFT, B by b_id;'

Comment: Left join doesn't keep the row order. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: @KlausHelenius Thanks for the correction. I've updated my answer with a way to do that.